# How can I define a template class which gives the pointer depth/level of a type?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, types

How can I define a template class which provides an integer constant representing the "depth" of a (pointer) type provided as the input template argument? For example, if the class was called `Depth`, the following would be true:

```
Depth<int ***>::value == 3
Depth<int>::value == 0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template <typename T> 
struct pointer_depth_impl
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template <typename T>
struct pointer_depth_impl<T* const volatile>
{
    enum { value = pointer_depth_impl<T const volatile>::value + 1 };
};

template <typename T>
struct pointer_depth
{
    enum { value = pointer_depth_impl<T const volatile>::value };
};
```

Comment: Thanks James, and the last sentence is very helpful too.

Comment: A trick is to always pass `T const volatile` down to the next recursion, and then only match against `<T *const volatile>`. This is somewhat of a hack, but it would work to avoid writing special const/volatile versions.

Comment: @Johannes:  Nice; that gets rid of the need for `<type_traits>`.  I don't think that's particularly hackish; at least, no more of a hack than a lot of other type traits :-)

Answer (score 4):

It could be done via recursion.

```
template<typename T>
struct Depth
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<typename T>
struct Depth<T*>
{
    enum { value = Depth<T>::value + 1 };
};
```

Comment: @Martin: would you explain why prefer enum?

Comment: @ rafak: Because enums will never need to have space allocated for value. In @Khaled original version he used static int variable. Though the compiler can in most situations optimize away the space requirements this is not always true.

Comment: I like enums too, but if you compare enums, say to statically find if two Depth templates have equal depth values, you will be faced with warnings. For example: `enum { value = Depth<I>::value == Depth<J>::value ? 1 : 0 };`