# Passing templated-function by reference in recursive template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion

In my PhD, I very often use matrices of various dimensions and data types. For first time, I use recursive templates in **C++11** for manipulating my non-contiguous arrays, so it is the last time I see `calloc` and `free`. With the help of stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323018/how-to-get-t-from-t-t-or-t-template-parameter) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520429/how-can-i-define-a-template-class-which-gives-the-pointer-depth-level-of-a-type) I achieved my initial goal of de&allocating them. Greedy me, I now want my class to perform the basic cellwise operations e.i. addition, division. It works fine if I use `enum` to determine which operation is performed, but I fail to use reference to an other templated function that performs the operation.

The main:

```
//Define the size of each dimension in a vector
int height = 3, width = 2;
std::vector<int> dimensions;
dimensions.push_back(height);
dimensions.push_back(width);

// Allocate a table of doubles 3x2
smatrix<double **> dbltbl(dimensions);
// Assign values in the cells
for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {
        dbltbl.uacc()[r][c] = (r * width + c) * 2.6;
    }

// Create a table of ints from the table of doubles (rounded copy)
smatrix<int **> inttbl = dbltbl;

// Add cell-wise the table of ints to the table of doubles
dbltbl.cellwise_add(inttbl);
```

**The `enum` way**

The `enum`:

```
enum clc_op { addition, subtration, multiplication, division };
```

The operation function:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
T add(S one, T two) {
    return one + two;
}
```

The recursive template solution:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
void cellwise_ops(S &src, T &dest, std::vector<int> dims, enum clc_op operation) {
    switch (operation) {
    case clc_op::addition:
        dest = add(src, dest);
        break;
    //…
    //...
    }
}

template <typename S, typename T>
void cellwise_ops(S *src, T *dest, std::vector<int> dims, enum clc_op operation) { 
    if (dims.size() == 0)
        return;
    int toimp = dims.front();
    dims.erase(dims.begin());
    for (int i = 0; i < toimp; ++i) {
        cellwise_ops(src[i], dest[i], dims, operation)
    }
}
```

The class method (e.g. P = double** and U=int**):

```
template <typename P>
template <typename U>
void smatrix<P>::cellwise_add(smatrix<U> const &addend) {
    U temp = addend.uacc();
    cellwise_ops(temp, _full, _dim, clc_op::addition);
}
```

The output:

```
==========================================
Table of doubles:
0   2.6 
5.2 7.8 
10.4    13  
==========================================
Table of ints from the table of doubles:
0   2   
5   7   
10  13  
==========================================
Table of doubles+ints:
0   4.6 
10.2    14.8    
20.4    26
```

This solution doesn’t look elegant, making me believe it is the wrong approach. So, I try to pass the operation as reference to function, and I fail hard time.

**The function by reference way:**

The addition (operation) function remains the same. The recursive solution:

```
template <typename S, typename T>
void cellwise_ops(S &src, T &dest, std::vector<int> dims, T (*operation)(S, T)) {
    dest = operation(src, dest);
}

template <typename S, typename T>
void cellwise_ops(S *src, T *dest, std::vector<int> dims, T (*operation)(S, T)) {
    if (dims.size() == 0)
        return;
    int toimp = dims.front();
    dims.erase(dims.begin());
    for (int i = 0; i < toimp; ++i) {
        cellwise_ops(src[i], dest[i], dims, operation);
    }
}
```

The class method:

```
template <typename P>
template <typename U>
void smatrix<P>::cellwise_add(smatrix<U> const &addend) {
    U temp = addend.uacc();
    cellwise_ops(temp, _full, _dim, add<U, P>);
}
```

The error:

```
./sm_example/smatrix.hpp:305:17:   required from ‘void smatrix<P>::cellwise_add(const smatrix<U>&) [with U = int**; P = double**]’
./sm_example/sm_example.cpp:157:35:   required from here
./sm_example/smatrix.hpp:159:19: error: invalid operands of types ‘double**’ and ‘double**’ to binary ‘operator+’
     return (T)one + two;
```

I understand that addition between pointers is not allowed, although I know it will not happen the compiler doesn't. I have no clue how I could work around it. How do I pass the operation’s template-function (`add`) by reference in the recursive template-function? Do I use templates in a wrong way?

I do not want to use `std::vector` for the time being, but comments are welcome.  Worst case scenario, my dataset reaches 100MBytes in 5 dimensions.

**Solution** in C++11 thx to @Yakk below

The operation function:

```
struct add {
  template <typename S, typename T> 
  S operator()(S &x, T &y) { return x + y; }
};
```

The rock bottom of recursive template solution:

```
template <typename S, typename T, class Op>
void cellwise_ops(S &src, T &dest, std::vector<int> dims, Op &&operation) {
  dest = operation(dest, src);
  return;
}
```

The class method:

```
template <typename P>
template <typename U>
void smatrix<P>::cellwise_add(smatrix<U> const &addend) {
  cellwise_ops(addend.uacc(), _full, _dim, add());
}
```

If you made it so far, thank you!
Chris

Comment: "I do not want to use std::vector for the time being" - why on earth not?

Comment: To be honest this code is a real mess. You should use meaningful template parameter names (and actual types passed) and get rid of C-style casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use function pointers.

```
template <typename S, typename T>
T add(S one, T two) {
  return (T)one + two;
}
const auto do_add=[](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto) {
  return add( decltype(args)(args)... );
};
```

or

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define DO_FUNC(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )

const auto do_add=DO_FUNC(add);
```

in both of these cases, we have a single object `do_add` that represents adding things.  This can also be written manually as a `struct` with an `operator()` if you care.

`do_add` isn't a function pointer.

```
template <class S, class T, class Op>
void cellwise_ops(S &src, T &dest, std::vector<int> dims, Op&& operation)     
{
  dest = operation(src, dest);
}

template <class S, class T, class Op>
void cellwise_ops(S *src, T *dest, std::vector<int> dims, Op&& operation)
{
  if (dims.size() == 0)
    return false;
  int toimp = dims.front();
  dims.erase(dims.begin());
  for (int i = 0; i < toimp; ++i) {
    cellwise_ops(src[i], dest[i], dims, operation);
  }
}
```

and we are done.

Comment: It took me a few moments to grasp the concept :D It works fine with C++14, but it will not compile in VS2012 (up to C++11). :(  
`use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14`

Comment: upvote for `RETURNS` macro, that is very nice, I can't believe I never saw that somewhere else.

Comment: @chris there is a proposal by Barry here to replace `RETURNS(blah)` with `=> blah` in lambdas for C++20.  I mention this because (a) it is nice and (b) I wish I didn't have to use a macro.

Comment: Very interesting. @Yakk it occurs to me that it would be nice if the => would be allowed not only for lambdas but for all functions. maybe all I really want is `noexcept(auto)` though. I am usually writing C++11 nowadays and I can't typically use `decltype(auto)` either yet, so I've been triplicating a lot of stuff, and already using macros to ease that burden... In some cases `RETURNS` is better than what I have been using though

Comment: @ChrisBeck `noexcept(auto)` would be what, the `&&` of all `noexcept` clauses for each line except those contained within `try{}catch(...)` blocks?  With `=>` the scope is at least limited to the single line return statement.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would hope for. If it's too hard to standardize that atm, they could restrict it to only functions that consist of a single return statement, like how `constexpr` was before c++14, and think about the multiline version later. Even just that would be pretty useful IMO. I think there was also a `noexcept(auto)` proposal that was rejected as not ready, idk if it's dead or coming back later

Comment: @Yakk I haven't solved my problem yet, maybe over the weekend. I am on a good learning curve based on your answer and I am thinking to scrap VS2012 and move everything to C++14 :D . Thanks.